# How to fixed "A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action "

Tags: android, github, github-actions

I have written a library for Android. When I run the Java with Gradle workflow on Github, I'm getting this error:

"A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
Android resource linking failed
ERROR: /home/runner/work/ExampleLibrary/ExampleLibrary/ExampleLibrary/build/intermediates/merged_res/release/values-v34/values-v34.xml:3: AAPT: error: resource android:color/system_background_dark not found."

Can any one give me any suggestions to overcome this problem?

I am using the (compileSdkVersion and targetSdk 34) implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0-alpha03' version in my build.gradle file. It has been suggested to use version 1.15.0-alpha03 of the material library, but I tried it and the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from `material:1.11.0` it is not finding the `system_background_dark` resource. Check if `material:1.10.0` works